# C# ComboBox values populated from XML

Tags: c#, xml, combobox

I'm just getting started programming and I'm in over my head. I've made a simple program that is basically a calculator so nothing too hard, once I got the grip of things. It's based off a similar program I made in flash but wanted to move up from Flash to C#. Even with Flash I needed help with XML, so don't think I'm very good with Flash ActionScript either.

What I'm trying to do is have a ComboBox that lists names from a XML file. Once a name is selected I want that name to go into a field, and 6 number values, also listed in the XML, populate several fields that are used in the calculations.

As a bonus, I want to be able to save to the XML file as well, something I couldn't do with Flash. When custom data is entered in the fields, it'd be nice to know how to save the data for later.

I've tried looking into this online, but only found solutions that I couldn't get to import so many values, or was something I couldn't understand. I'm trying but this is the first time I've made a real program. Thank you to anyone willing to help me out.

Comment: The best approach is to show code which you have tried, and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of how to add xml element to a combo box.  You might have to tweak it a bit.

```
  XmlDocument sFor = new XmlDocument();
        sFor.Load(Path.GetFullPath("Source/SearchForTerminator.xml"));
        XmlNodeList SearchList = sFor.SelectNodes("SearchFor/SearchValue");
        foreach (XmlNode Search in SearchList)
        {
            cbxSearchFor.Items.Add(Search.InnerText);
        }
```

This is what my xml file look like:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
 <SearchFor>
     <SearchValue>\u2026</SearchValue>
     <SearchValue>\u0015</SearchValue>
</SearchFor>
```

Hope this help and guide you in the right direction.

Comment: Looks, like I still have a lot of figure out :S thanks